# IF exist for scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a batch file to check if scheduled task exists and if they don't create them, however, my if exist rule seem to always hit true even though the jobs are not there.

Any ideas?

```
::Check Rule
IF EXIST SchTasks /QUERY /TN "Cache Task Morning"  ( 
    echo ! Morning rule in place!
    GOTO NEXT 
) ELSE IF NOT EXIST SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Cache Task Morning" /TR "C:\Cache Clear\Cache Clear.bat" /ST 09:00 

:NEXT
IF EXIST SchTasks /QUERY /TN "Cache Task Afternoon"  ( 
    echo ! Afternoon rule in place!
    GOTO NEXT TWO
) ELSE IF NOT EXIST SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Cache Task Afternoon" /TR "C:\Cache Clear\Cache Clear.bat" /ST 15:00 

:NEXT TWO
IF EXIST SchTasks  /QUERY /TN "Cache Task Evening"  ( 
    echo ! Evening rule in place!
    GOTO CLEAR CACHE 
) ELSE IF NOT EXIST SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Cache Task Evening" /TR "C:\Cache Clear\Cache Clear.bat" /ST 18:00
```

Comment: You cant use `IF EXIST`/`IF NOT EXIST` like that, you need to run `SchTasks` and capture either the output or `ErrorLevel` and run your commmands according to what they return.

Comment: Open a new command prompt window, type `help if` or `if /?` and read the help very carefully; you will learn what `if exist` is for...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot use `if exist` with `schtasks`, this is not the purpose of `if exist`.

use either

```
schtasks /query /TN "task_name" >NUL 2>&1 || schTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "task_name" ...
```

or

```
schtasks /query /TN "task_name" >NUL 2>&1
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 schTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "task_name" ...
```

`>NUL 2>&1` suppress success or error output, but we have `errorlevel` set to `0` if success, or not `0` if failure.

Both are pretty the same. In the first case we use the cmd `&&` and `||` operators, where `&&` means previous command succesful and `||` means previous command failed.

as in

`mycommand && echo success || echo error`

As we only want to test failure, then use only `||` (previous command failed).